# Inner product problem.NET examination problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with real entries. Let us define $(x,y)_A:=(Ax,Ay)$ where $x,y\in \mathbb  R^n$. What is the necessary and sufficient condition for $(\cdot,\cdot)$ to be an inner product?

My options are $A$ is an orthogonal matrix or $A$ is an non null matrix. Please solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is orthogonal, that means precisely that $(Ax,Ay)=(x,y)$; so this condition is sufficient. But it is not necessary.

In the case of an arbitrary matrix, think of a singular matrix.

Comment: I know for singular matrix the inner product can not be defined.but if A is any non singular matrix,then is  the result true?

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ \ $